# Unable to understand how objects work in Python

Tags: python, object, reference

I am learning Python and noticed this program.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.printInfo = self.name + " is " + self.age + " years old!"

jack = Person("Jack", "30")
print(jack.name)
print(jack.age)
print(jack.printInfo)

jack.name = "Abel"
print(jack.name)
print(jack.printInfo)
```

Why does the last print statement print "Jack" instead of Abel?

Comment: Because the attribute `printInfo` is only assigned and evaluated once at the time the object is initialised. You'd get the same effect without using a `class` and just individual variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before `self.printInfo` is initialized in `__init__` so changing `self.name` will not change it. If you want a dynamic `Person` representation you can override `__str__`

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " is " + self.age + " years old!"


jack = Person("Jack", "30")
print(jack.name)
print(jack.age)
print(jack) # Jack is 30 years old!

jack.name = "Abel"
jack.age = "25"
print(jack.name)
print(jack) # Abel is 25 years old!
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the object `jack`, it creates `self.printInfo` in the initialiser. It sets `self.printInfo = self.name + " is " + self.age + " years old!"`, i.e, `self.printInfo = Jack is 30 years old!`.

This is a constant value. It does not change when self.name changes.

Comment: Would be helpful for the OP to mention using `printInfo` as a method to get the desired result